# LogPlot and LogLogPlot do not output their legends correctly

Tags: plotting, legending

[image: LogLogPlot does not output legends correctly]

When I give lists of functions to `LogPlot` or `LogLogPlot` with the option of `PlotLegends`, 
the output legends only have its first one, just like on the image below.

What should I do to get all legends in the plot?

Comment: `Evaluate@pdata` in the second plot, but you really should make `pdata` a function... and please, in the future, post code, not images. See the help for information on how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Evaluate` for your variable will allow `PlotLegends` to work. For example:

```
llist = {1, 2, 3};
pdata = {x, x^2, x^3};
LogLogPlot[Evaluate@pdata, {x, 1, 10}, PlotLegends -> llist]
```

gives:[image]

or

```
LogPlot[Evaluate@pdata, {x, 1, 10}, PlotLegends -> llist]
```

[image]